# is 'rolling' participle or adjective?

Tags: adjectives, parts-of-speech, present-participles

> A rolling stone gathers no moss

Here is "rolling" an adjective or a present participle?

If it is both, which one is more accurate? If you have to choose one, which one would you choose? Adjective or Present Participle? Why?

Comment: I hope Araucaraia and I have answered your question (I edited my answer)

Answer (score 1):

This is a present participle verb, due to 3 reasons:

1. not modifiable by "very" etc.
2. not possible as complement of verb "become"
3. in terms of meaning this `-ing` word means 'in the process' of rolling

Comment: You could make your post better by giving examples, if you wanted.